# How to limit event subscription in Blazor component initialization

Tags: c#, .net-core, event-handling, blazor

When I try to subscribe to an event at initialization of a blazor component, each time the page is refreshed or navigated to, the OnInitializedAsync method gets called again and again, then the invocation list of the event increases alot. How to limit the hookup for one time only?

```
@code {
[Parameter]
public CustomerModel model { get; set; }


protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    model.PropertyChangedEvent += PropertyChanged;

}
}
```

Comment: what is your desired behavior?
1) each instance of a page/component shall only subscribe once?
2) on your singleton instance of "CustomerModel" only on page/component instance should be subscribed.

Comment: CustomerModel is singleton, there is only one instance of it, even you open same page (same component) in many tabs or machines. When injected into a blazor component, I would want the component to subscribe to the propertyChangedEvent of the model, then when model has some change, it will notify the component to invoke the StateHasChanged value to update UI. But because the OnInitializedAsync method is called each time the page is navigated to, I still want a single subscription to the event to avoid calling StateHasChanged many time. So 2 is my desired behavior.

Comment: you dont want each component to subscribe and be notified of propertychanges?, instead only the first? 
if each component should subscribe only once, then @Alex - Tin Le`s answer is what you are looking for.
if only one single instance of a component ever should subscribe you need to check it (via GetInvocationList() etc.) and only subscribe if none is already present there.

Comment: In my case, one single compopent in single page should subscribe to the event for one time only. 
@Alex Tin Le solution  is not working. I tried navigate the page back and forth then the InvocationList count still increases. 
I am aware of using GetInvocationList method, but it must be place in the base class of the model class, which is not strait forward as it requires distinguish of each component that registers to the event. 
Wish that blazor component had method  which is called once only just like initializeComponent in Winforms

Comment: as from your informations is would asume, that each time "OnInitializedAsync" is called it is in an other instance of your component. so when navigating away and then again to your page a second instance is created and that second instance subscribes. You can verify this by making a breakpoint in the "OnInitializedAsync" and create an "ObjectId" on "this" (rightclick on "this" -> make object Id), same on the second call and then compare the IDs ($1, $2, ...). In this scenario both answers are valid and working.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, whenever I bind an event, I always unbind it first. This is to make sure only 1 same handler is bound only once.

```
model.PropertyChangedEvent -= PropertyChanged;
model.PropertyChangedEvent += PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: it wont work. I have tried and it still add subscription: attached is immediate widowns: 
   model.PropertyChangedEvent.GetInvocationList()
{System.Delegate[4]}
    [0]: {Method = {Void PropertyChanged()}}
    [1]: {Method = {Void PropertyChanged()}}
    [2]: {Method = {Void PropertyChanged()}}
    [3]: {Method = {Void PropertyChanged()}}

Answer (score 1):

[Implement `IDispoable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components#idisposable) to unsubscibe to the event.

```cs
@implement IDisposable
...
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public CustomerModel model { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        model.PropertyChangedEvent += PropertyChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        model.PropertyChangedEvent -= PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: still problem. My model class is singleton, however when same page is opened in other tab or browser, the event still hooks up twice or more. I am thinking of trying to have a static boolean variable to mark that event is already hooked up, then subsequent call is ignore, however i am not sure when the life cycle of the page is end, what happens when new instance is created

Comment: This will not work with a static bool, only the first page instance will subscribe to your event.

Comment: Man thanks a lot! This was the last piece I was missing the whole time. I had similar issue as OP but I don't have singleton and implementing `IDisposable` interface is way to go and correctly unsubscribe the event.

Comment: In my case it was a simple DI problem; my service was registered as singleton, so event hooks added up and never got disposed..